# display bootstrap datepicker date in different language then submit date in English in asp.net razor view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using bootstrap-datepicker in my asp.net core application. The datepicker includes the language option so that the datepicker displays months/days e.t.c in the chosen language.
However , when I come submit the form , I'd like to submit the english representation of the date selected.
Jquery validate fails on submit.

datepicker options

```
 <script src="~/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/js/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js"></script>
    

     $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                    format: "dd M yyyy",
                    language:  "es",
                    weekStart: 1,
                    maxViewMode: 2,
                    todayHighlight: true,
                    startDate: startDate,
                    daysOfWeekDisabled: [],
                    showOnfocus: true,
                    autoClose: true,
                    orientation: "bottom"
                });
```

asp.net taghelper

```
<input type="text" asp-for="JoiningDate" asp-format="{0:dd MMM yyyy}" class="datepicker"/>
```

Since the text field receives the translated dates in this case in spanish , the validation fails on submit.
Ideally I'd want to submit the date in the english format but view the picker in the selected language.
I've tried to change the datepicker language option back to english in the submit function but that hasn't worked.

Comment: What is the type of `JoiningDate` field?
And what do you mean by jquery validate fail? Please provide the complete code and information, otherwise we cannot help you reproduce and solve the problem.

Comment: @YongqingYu `JoiningDate` is a c# date variable coming from a c# model class. Validation failing means the required datefield doesn't  recognize the date format as it is rendered on the text field in a  different language.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to recognize when you pass the date to the action after clicking submit, then I suggest you **use ajax to pass it manually**.

You can get the selected date in jquery and convert it into a format that can be passed.

For details, please refer to the following case:

```
public class MyModelDate
{
    public DateTime JoiningDate { get; set; }

}
```

View:

```
@model MyModelDate
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "DateTest";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>DateTest</h1>

<form asp-action="DateTest" method="post">
    Date: <input type="text" asp-for="JoiningDate" asp-format="{0:dd MMM yyyy}" class="datepicker" />
    <span asp-validation-for="JoiningDate" class="text-danger"></span>
    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

@section Scripts{
    <link href="~/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="~/bootstrap-datepicker/js/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
             format: "dd M yyyy",
             language:  "es",
             weekStart: 1,
             maxViewMode: 2,
             todayHighlight: true,
             startDate: startDate,
             daysOfWeekDisabled: [],
             showOnfocus: true,
             autoClose: true,
             orientation: "bottom"
        });
        $("form").submit(function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            //get datepicker selected date and convert to ISO string format
            var date = $('.datepicker').data('datepicker').date.toISOString();
            var MyModelDate = {
                JoiningDate: date
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: "/Home/DateTest",
                data: MyModelDate

            })
        });

    </script>
}
```

Here is the test result:

[image]